# Where is the parent html file in the Django app?

Tags: python, django

There is a Django app (Cartoview) i am trying to modify. This is the code for it's `base.html` file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% block extra_head %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
{% block tabs %}
<li><a href="{% url 'app_manager_base_url' %}">{% trans "Apps" %}</a></li>
{{block.super}}
<li><a href="{% url 'app_manager_base_url' %}">{% trans "Apps" %} asd</a></li>
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
{% include 'cartoview/footer.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

now here there are 3 tabs inside `block.super` which is inherited from `base.html` file as seen above. I want to change those tabs. But when i see the parent file then it says above `extends base.html`. The problem is that this file itself is named `base.html` and there is no other file of this name in this same directory. I want to locate the parent file so to change those tabs. Kindly help thanks.

Comment: I don't think `base` can extend `base` it seems like an invalid project structure...

Comment: I talked to a senior and he says that ```base.html``` means that it is django's own template

Answer (score 0):

The `base.html` it's in the root of your declared path for your templates, in your settings search for:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        [ ... ]
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        [ ... ]
    },
]
```

The key `'DIRS'` tells you where it is the templates folder, inside of it you will find the base.html